# How to cleanly implement two objects referring to eachother using shared/weak pointers in c++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Entity {
    vector<weak_ptr<Entity> > aboveMe;
    vector<weak_ptr<Entity> > belowMe;

    void addBelow(weak_ptr<Entity> below)
    {
        belowMe.push_back(below);
    }

    void addAbove(weak_ptr<Entity> above)
    {
        aboveMe.push_back(below);
    }
}
```

This must always be true:

```
If an Entity A is above an Entity B, B is below A and vice versa.
```

What would be the most elegant way to represent this?

Currently, it is possible for client code to simply call:

```
a->addBelow(b).
```

However, without a corresponding call to

```
b->addAbove(a)
```

the invariant is violated!

In Java, one would do something like this:

```
void addBelow(Entity below)
{
    belowMe.add(below);
    below.addAbove(this); // With obviously some mechanism to prevent infinite recursion
}
```

What is the best way to do this in C++ when using shared/weak pointers?

Comment: Are all of your `Entity` store in a bigger structure? If so, you could store [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead of shared/weak pointers. Otherwise you should have a look at [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: Yes, the objects are stored as a vector of shared_ptr<Entity> in a larger "Scene Model" object which handles storage and allocation. Should I then make those unique_ptr and then use those reference_wrappers to create the references between objects?

Comment: If these objects are already stored in `shared_ptr` elsewhere, you should use `enable_shared_from_this` (see Smeeheey's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a similar approach in C++. If an object is designed to have its lifetime managed by shared pointers, it can inherit from the template class `std::enable_shared_from_this`, like so:

```
class Entity : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Entity> { ...
```

You can then create shared pointers safely from the `this` pointer. Then the approach:

```
void addBelow(weak_ptr<Entity> below)
{
    belowMe.push_back(below);
    below.addAbove(shared_from_this());
}
```

would be close to what you need.

Something to point out here: as it stands there is no ownership relationship between the objects in your chain, so this works provided the objects are 'owned' from the outside.

If you wanted to allow an ownership hierarchy, you could additionally change your chain so that objects 'own downwards':

```
vector<weak_ptr<Entity> > aboveMe;
vector<shared_ptr<Entity> > belowMe;
```

Note: you certainly wouldn't want shared pointers for both directions, as then you would have circular ownership whereby objects would never be released.

Note 2: The `shared_ptr` class can be constructed from `weak_ptr` references, and vice-versa. So irrespective of which ownership hierarchy you choose the `addBelow` suggestion above works without modification.

Comment: You would need to lock() below to get a shared_ptr if you want to call it's function members

Comment: This works! Yes, the objects are owned by another object. Thank you!